# myLocation.getBearing() returns 0.0

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, bearing

I need to constantly check the bearing of the phone so I can rotate the map so it follows the user direction.

So, I called `map.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

and in a background thread, I check this each 2 seconds:

```
currentBearing = map.getMap().getMyLocation().getBearing();
```

However, this ALWAYS, no matter what, returns 0.0

Also, when I rotate the device while using Google Maps app, it rotates the map exactly as I want to.

What am I doing wrong?

Side note: Tested on Samsung Galaxy S II running 4.0.4 and Nexus 4 running 4.2.2

Comment: And does `map.getMap().getMyLocation().hasBearing()` return `true`?

Comment: Nope, it returns false. How can I add the bearing to that Location? I mean, I bet the Location that the Google Maps gets has a Bearing.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example. It uses a location listener and LocationManager to update every xxxx milisecs

http://randamblings.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/day-2-mapviews-and-locations/